# C++ map custom hash function gives compile error when using "count" function

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I tried to make a custom hash function, which transforms original string to "the number of times each alphabet appears in a given string". It goes like this :

```
struct hash_nums {
    string operator()(const string& s) const {
        
        vector<int> arr(26, 0);
        for (char c : s) {
            ++arr[c-'a'];
        }
        string str(arr.begin(), arr.end());
        return str;
    }
};
```

and in main function, I wrote code like this :

```
unordered_map<string, vector<string>, hash_nums> um;
...
for (string s : strings)
    if (um.count(s)) // do something
```

but when I use `um.count(s)`, it gives me this error :

```
Line 32: Char 20: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>, Solution::hash_nums, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>>>>>::count' requested here
            if (um.count(s)) {
                   ^
```

I used custom hash function for std::pair, and it didn't give me these errors.
Also, only declaring unordered_map compiles just fine.

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Note: That is only a portion of the error message. It may be tricky to reproduce the whole error message without a [mre].

Comment: Isn't a hash function supposed to return `std::size_t`? Why are you returning a string?

Comment: Indeed, a hash function cannot return a string.  This function's very design is egregiously sinful.  It allocates a vector, then constructs a string.  The performance hit would be disgusting.  Unordered maps are intended to be light-weight and performant alternatives to a search tree.  But I guarantee that even if this hash function worked it would be significantly worse than just storing strings in a `std::map`.